# Ubuntu -- Change the default program used to open a type of file

Tags: ubuntu

How can I configure Ubuntu to open files of a given type (e.g. file.tex) with a given program (e.g. emacs)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files), right click one of those files, choose "Properties" from the context menu and set your preferences with the "Open with" option.

Comment: The thing I really like is if you have just three apps listed there, they appear in the first level of the right click menu. Any more, and on the default one appears with the others in a sub menu. I'm constantly removing apps from the menu - I don't need 5 text editors and 5 browsers listed for a HTML file ;)

Comment: I know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of editing defaults.list, I find it easier to use the xdg-mime program. Looking up the pdf viewer, seeing its adobe, and switching it to KPDF:

```
$xdg-mime query default application/pdf
AdobeReader.desktop
$xdg-mime default kde-kpdf.desktop application/pdf
$xdg-mime query default application/pdf
kde-kpdf.desktop
```

And you can use xdg-open to open a file with your preferred application:

```
$xdg-open file.pdf
```

Comment: +1. Excellent. I wasn't aware of this tool. I'd prefer this too to editing the file directly.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Properties tab on a file to change the program used to open it, as Manni pointed out.

**Edit:** *Have a look at Chris089's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/21626/ubuntu-change-the-default-program-used-to-open-a-type-of-file/21687#21687). I'd prefer that to directly editing the files as I suggested below. It might still be useful to know what the mime-types are and where the associations lie, but I'd use the tool to modify the file.*

However, if you want a text-based solution, or even to have a look at how file-associations are configured for different types:

- The file associations are stored for each individual user in **~/.local/share/applications/default.list**. You can edit this to point to a .desktop file (which represents the executable)

> $ cat ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list 
>   [Default Applications] 
>   application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml=Google-googleearth.desktop 
>   application/keyhole=Google-googleearth.desktop 
>   application/earthviewer=Google-googleearth.desktop 
>   application/vnd.google-earth.kmz=Google-googleearth.desktop

- At the global system-wide level, associations are held in **/usr/share/applications/defaults.list**. So, if I wanted to effect a system-wide change for all audio files for example, this is where I'd need to look to get all the mime-types. You then have a choice between changing the file types directly here, or overriding them in your local defaults.list

> $ cat
>   /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
>   | grep ^audio 
>   audio/3gpp=totem.desktop
>   audio/ac3=totem.desktop
>   audio/AMR=totem.desktop
>   audio/AMR-WB=totem.desktop
>   audio/basic=totem.desktop
>   audio/midi=totem.desktop
>   audio/mp4=totem.desktop
>   audio/mpeg=totem.desktop
>   audio/mpegurl=totem.desktop
>   audio/ogg=totem.desktop
>   audio/prs.sid=totem.desktop
>   audio/vnd.rn-realaudio=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-ape=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-flac=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-gsm=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-it=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-m4a=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-matroska=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-mod=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-mp3=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-mpeg=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-mpegurl=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-ms-asf=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-ms-asx=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-ms-wax=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-ms-wma=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-musepack=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-pn-aiff=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-pn-au=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-pn-realaudio=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-pn-wav=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-pn-windows-acm=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-realaudio=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-real-audio=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-sbc=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-scpls=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-speex=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-tta=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-wav=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-wavpack=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-vorbis=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-vorbis+ogg=totem.desktop
>   audio/x-xm=totem.desktop

Here is the [**Desktop Entry Specification**](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) document that details the need for and use of a .desktop file (instead of using the path to the executable ).

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.10 there isn´t ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list I had to edit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list