# Changing default media player in Fedora 11?

Tags: vlc-media-player, fedora-11

I've downloaded & installed VLC, and it works fine.

However, I can't figure out how to set it to be the default - under Preferences -> Preferred Applications, Multimedia changing the "Multimedia Player" command doesn't seem to do anything.

How is this set?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? (Gnome, KDE, etc)

Comment: I'm using Gnome.

Comment: Could you please sent me the steps required to install vlc in a Fedora 11 PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this the old-fashioned way, by right-clicking a file of the type you want VLC to play, and selecting VLC as the player to use in the *Open With..* menu item.

Alternatively, you can specify the mime-types you want VLC to handle by following the steps on the VLC wiki page: [How to make VLC the default player](http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_make_VLC_the_default_player#Changing_the_default_application_for_videos_manually.28the_hard_way.29:). This procedure will work for any kind of media you wish to configure.

Have a look at my answer on how to change default apps on Ubuntu [by configuring the mime-types](https://superuser.com/questions/21626/ubuntu-change-the-default-program-used-to-open-a-type-of-file/21642#21642). The file location might be different on Fedora, but the procedure should remains the same because it is how Gnome behaves.